# Android stretch background image while dragging the imageview

Tags: android, scrollview, drag, ontouchlistener

I am try to implement the **vertical slider** of **image control**. The image is inside the `ScrollView`. When it comes to vertical dragging of `ImageView`, the top margin of relative layout always provide different reading.

If it is greater than 600 something while dragging down, the background image of the relative layout stretch vertically together with the image position I have dragged.

```
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:fillViewport="true" >
...


   <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayouyt6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rTop"
                android:background="@drawable/plain" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/dragImage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/arrow_one"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Would you please tell me how to

1. get the offset I have scrolled in my scrollview ?
2. I know it is get touch position minus scrolled position and plus image Y position, how to implement this parameter after finishing dragging ?
3. How to set relative boundary for imageview inside the relative layout ? is it wiser to take this background image out as the imageview?
4. If I programmatically repositioning of 6 relativelayouts but coming up to the same width  , would it affect the scrolling position and the scollview total Height ? If so , How to calculate the offset Y for the repositioning ?

The below is my code as of February 11:

```
dragImage.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
                //private int _xDelta;
                private int _yDelta;
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);



                final float y = event.getY();

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //_yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                    mOldY2 = y;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mViewPager.setPagingEnabled(true);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    btn4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fbl02);
                    final float dy = y - mOldY2;
                    mNewY2 += dy;
                    mOldY2 = y;
                    System.out.println(mNewY2);                 

                    while(mNewY2 > 224){
                        mNewY2 -= 224;
                    }

                    while(mNewY2 < 157){
                        mNewY2 += 157;
                    }


                    if(mNewY2 < 157 || mNewY2 > 224)
                        break;

                    v.setTranslationY((int)mNewY2);

                    v.invalidate();

                    float power = (float) ( 51.5/67 -(0.2/67) * mNewY2) ;
                    System.out.println(power);

                    Float roundF = new Float( Math.round(power));
                    midBandStick = roundF;
                    btn4.setText(String.valueOf(midBandStick) );
                    //}
                    //break;
                }
                return true;

            }
```

The below is my code :

```
public static void setRLBelowAnother(RelativeLayout rA , RelativeLayout rB   ){         
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rparam4 =  
                (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) rB.getLayoutParams();
        rparam4.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, rA.getId());              
        rB.setLayoutParams(rparam4);             
    } 



            setRLBelowAnother(rTop , r1);
            setRLBelowAnother(r1 , r2);
            setRLBelowAnother(r2 , r6  );
            setRLBelowAnother(r6 , r3  );
            setRLBelowAnother(r3 , r4 );
            setRLBelowAnother(r4 , r5  );
    dragImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        dragImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.slide_lshort);

        dragImage.setX((float) (0.15*screenWidth));
        dragImage.setY((float) (0.05*screenHeight));
        dragImage.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
            //private int _xDelta;
            private int _yDelta;
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                final int X = (int) event.getX();
                final int Y = (int) event.getY();
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:



                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) dragImage
                    .getLayoutParams();

                    //_xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                    _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mViewPager.setPagingEnabled(true);

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    midStick = 0.2f;
                    btn4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fbl02);

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ParamsA = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) dragImage
                    .getLayoutParams();
                    //ParamsA.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                    ParamsA.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                    //ParamsA.rightMargin = -250;
                    ParamsA.bottomMargin = -250;
                    mViewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);


                    int offYb = 0;
                    int pos = ParamsA.topMargin +  offYb ;
                    if(pos > -52 &&  pos < 582 ){
                        dragImage.setLayoutParams(ParamsA);
                        System.out.println(ParamsA.topMargin);
                        float power = (float) (100 + (900/634) * ParamsA.topMargin) ;
                        Float roundF = new Float( Math.round(power));
                        midStick = roundF;
                        btn4.setText(String.valueOf(midStick));

                    }
                    break;
                }
                return true;

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Call the `getScrollY()` method from the `ScrollView` to get the Y index (scrolled index)
2. If I understood (otherwise please correct me) you could get a frame (boundary) between the ImageView and the RelativeLayout adding padding or margin to the ImageView. You just need to call android:padding="" or android:margin=""
3. The height of the `ScrollView` will change and also the `scrollY` if the new added RelativeLayout/ImageView doesn't completely fit on the available space. When you finish adding the new layout you could get the scrollY from the ScrollView and see where the ScrollView has scrolled to.

Can you improve the questions 2, 3 and 4? It's quite confusing.